# Existen las class en jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Quisiera saber si existe en jQuery algo similar a esto

```
class Area{
public function data(){
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery no es un lenguaje, es una biblioteca o "framework" - el lenguaje es JavaScript.

En JavaScript no hay clases, propiamente hablando. Es un lenguaje orientado a objetos, pero no mediante clases sino mediante prototipos.

De todas maneras, hay varios patterns que se parecen bastante a lo que los que venimos de Java/C++/Php/Python/C# estamos más acostumbrados. Lo común es definir el esqueleto de esta pseudo-clase en una función (por convención, empieza en mayúscula) que funcionará como una especie de constructor de nuevos objectos, cuando se llame con `new`. Ejemplo:

```
function Usuario() {

    var nombre = "";

    this.getNombre = function() {
         return this.nombre;
    };
}

var u1 = new Usuario();
var u2 = new Usuario();
```

Comment: Yo creería que las clases **sí** existen en Javascript a partir de ES6, aún si no es exactamente lo que se pregunta: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @Shaz En la práctica (actual) y en el contexto de quien pregunta, eso es como si no existiera.

Answer (score 2):

Si queres usar clases tenes que usar `EcmaScript 2016` en la que si existen las clases.

Usa un transpilador como [Babel JS](https://babeljs.io/), que pasa de la versión `ecmascript 5` a `ecmascript2016` es facil de usar 
un tutorial_:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bopDGwJFTv4

`babel` viene por modulos, dependiendo de lo queres usar. Si queres clases, usar el modulo de clases, o de el funciones, el de templates string

En `JQUERY` en su ultima version aún no podes usar clases como vos queres, aún no se puede.